# How to Post multipart/form-data for a File Upload using SpringMVC and MockMVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I've created a photo uploader that works great using javax.ws.rs.  Here's the signature and basic gist of it:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload/photo")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
public String uploadPhoto(InputStream stream){
        try {
            int read = 0;
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            CountingOutputStream out = new CountingOutputStream(fos);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE];

            while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO throw!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    //...
}
```

I can test this using apache.commons.httpClient library like this:

```
    @Test
    public void testUpload() {

        int statusCode = 0;
        String methodResult = null;

        String endpoint = SERVICE_HOST + "/upload/photo";

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(endpoint);

        File file = new File("/home/me/Desktop/someFolder/image.jpg");

        FileRequestEntity entity = new FileRequestEntity(file, "multipart/form-data");

        post.setRequestEntity(entity);

        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(post);
            methodResult = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        statusCode = post.getStatusCode();

        post.releaseConnection();
            //...
    }
```

This works great!  The problem is that the rest of the application is written using Spring MVC.  When I use Spring Mock MVC testing framework the program just hangs (shown in the code snippet below this one).  Here is the SpringMVC code for the uploader:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(    produces="application/json",
                    consumes="multipart/form-data",
                    method=RequestMethod.POST,
                    value="/photo")
public String uploadPhoto(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile){

            try {
                int read = 0;
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                CountingOutputStream out = new CountingOutputStream(fos);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE];

                while ((read = multipartFile.getInputStream().read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                }

                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO throw!
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //...
}
```

And below is what I've implemented for testing, using Spring Mock MVC.  I think the problem has to do with using fileUpload(...).  Is there a way to test using the normal post(..) instead, like I can with apache? I'd prefer to use an InputStream as the argument and avoid using a MultipartFile.

```
@Test
public void testUpload() throws Exception {

    String endpoint = BASE_URL + "/upload/photo";

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/home/me/Desktop/someFolder/image.jpg");
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", fis);

    mockMvc.perform(fileUpload(endpoint)
            .file(multipartFile)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use Spring MVC and the Spring Mock MVC framework, but the code I've provided just hangs on the while statement.  Is what I'm doing correct as far as using the fileUpload method in the Spring test?  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Longish code example... something goes wrong somewhere... What's your actual question? -1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. To add content to a mock post request use content(bytes[])
2. media type parameter boundary was necessary

Also, it was safe to use a plain old InputStream from java.io as a parameter for the upload method, and still use MockMultipartFile in the request.

```
@Test
public void testUpload() throws Exception {

            String endpoint = BASE_URL + "/upload/photo";

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/home/me/Desktop/someDir/image.jpg");
            MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", fis);

            HashMap<String, String> contentTypeParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
            contentTypeParams.put("boundary", "265001916915724");
            MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", contentTypeParams);

            mockMvc.perform(
                    post(endpoint)
                    .content(multipartFile.getBytes())
                    .contentType(mediaType))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this works, but I think that each part of multi-part message should begin with a boundary, `--265001916915724` in your case.

Comment: Why not use MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload instead of post?

Comment: Why combine Jax-RS with Spring MVC in one web app? This does not make sense to me

Comment: This code didn't work out for me, where are you passing the "file" in the perform call? It will keep complain about the missing @RequestPart("file") as you use only the content in the mockMvc.perform: .content(multipartFile.getBytes())

Comment: Thank you so much. It even works with org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload stream uploading !

Answer (score 4):

MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload:

```
@Test
public void uploadTest() throws Exception {
    String endpoint = "/service/productsale/5/upload";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\test\\test.jpg");
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",fis);

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload(endpoint).file(multipartFile))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeExists("imageVo"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: > Note that, starting Spring 5.0, MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload() has been deprecated in favor of MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart() method. [Link to article](https://www.logicbig.com/examples/spring-mvc/file-upload/spring-mock-mvc-request-builders-multipart.html)

Answer (score 3):

By referring to the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-performing-requests), the code below can be more simple.

```
@Test
public void testFileUpload() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("/Downloads/WX.png");
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile(
            "image",
            "WX20180207-134704@2x.png",
            "image/png",
            input);
    this.mockMvc
            .perform(
                multipart("/api/note/image/create")
                        .file(file)
                        .header("Authorization", "BearereyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9")
            );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This link helped me: https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/

More specifically this configuration:
    @Override

```
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```